# how to bring up containers with hostname and ip addresses such that they run serially?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-network

Here is sample docker compose configuration for bringing up a simple directory listing service(`dirlist`):

```
version: "3"
services:
  dirlist:
    image: ubuntu-python
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: "172.19.0.10"
    hostname: maca
    volumes:
      - /home/arun/misc:/misc
    working_dir: /misc

  curlcmd:
    image: ubuntu-curl
    command: curl -s http://maca:8000/readme1.txt
    extra_hosts:
      - "maca:172.19.0.10"
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      app_net:

networks:
  app_net:
    ipam:
       driver: default
       config:
         - subnet: "172.19.0.0/24"
```

I want to create replicas of `dirlist` such that each containers spawned thereof have the following:

1. ip addresses should be serial. For e.g. 1st container must have ip address `172.19.0.10`, 2nd one - `172.19.0.11`, 3rd - `172.19.0.12`, and, so on...Ip addresses being selected randomly from a range is also okay, however, #3 requirement should also be met.
2. Their hostnames should also appear to have serial pattern - say the 1st container has `dirlist1` as hostname, 2nd one has `dirlist2`, etc...
3. All such containers (of `dirlist`) should also appear as `extra_hosts` (with their corresponding names and ip addresses) for the service which depend on `dirlist` (i.e. `curlcmd` as per example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the networking functionality you describe, [Docker Compose does on its own](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/): it can assign IPv4 addresses within some range (a unique CIDR block per Docker private network), and it provides an internal DNS system so that service names are directly usable as host names, without specifying `extra_hosts`.  That is, with a single replica, this much shorter Compose file will work just fine:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  dirlist:
    image: ubuntu-python
  curlcmd:
    image: ubuntu-curl
    command: curl -s http://dirlist:8000/readme1.txt
```

I am relying on the `default` network provided by Compose out-of-the-box, assuming that the files you want to run are `COPY`ed into your Docker image, and also assuming the Dockerfile has the correct `WORKDIR` already.  I've skipped all of the `networks:` setup to use the defaults, and there's no particular need to set a per-container `hostname:` (it doesn't do anything visible outside the container itself).

Compose on its own doesn't directly support replicated services.  If you run this in combination with Docker's Swarm cluster service, you can specify [`replicas:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas) for the `dirlist` service and I think that essentially meets your requirements, but for a single host you may not want to set up Swarm.

The other thing you can do is use a text templating tool to create the `docker-compose.yml` file.  For example, using [Jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/), I might write:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
{%- for i in range(1, 6) %}
  dirlist{{ i }}:
    image: ubuntu-python
{%- endfor %}
  curlcmd:
    image: ubuntu-curl
    command: curl -s http://dirlist1:8000/readme1.txt
```

In Compose there's no way for the `curlcmd` container to discover how many replicas there are, though if it knows they follow this specific pattern it can simply iterate through hostnames until it fails.